# i have downloaded yED-3.14.3_64-bit_setup.sh, but i don't know what code to run next

Tags: software-installation

I have downloaded yED-3.14.3_64-bit_setup.sh, but I do not know where to go from here. I am a new Ubuntu user and i need to get some network diagramming software.

Comment: A link to where you got that file from might be useful. Thanks.

Comment: If you found the answer below answered your question, then accept it by click the grey tick under the answer's downvote button to make it go green and colourful **:)**

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>:

- Move to the working directory with `cd /path/to/file`.
- Make it executable with `chmod +x yED-3.14.3_64-bit_setup.sh`.
- Run it with `sudo yED-3.14.3_64-bit_setup.sh`